# Wordpress: Remove Classes from Custom added Links

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know if there is any way to remove classes from only from custom links? At least, I want to remove these classes from my custom links "current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent" - not from dynamic links.

I am using this piece of code:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('page_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
    return is_array($var) ? array_intersect($var, array('current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent')) : '';
}
```

It is removing css classes from all static and dynamic links. I just want to remove css classes from custom links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check to see if the link contains the `menu-item-object-custom` class and use the result to filter the CSS classes selectively:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('page_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
function my_css_attributes_filter($classes) {
    // if this is not a custom link and not the home page, return the $classes intact, otherwise filter $classes 
    return is_array($classes) ? 
        (in_array("menu-item-object-custom", $classes) || is_front_page())? 
            array_diff($classes, array('current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent'))
            : $classes // not a custom link
        : ''; // not an array
}
```

Comment: Mate Very Nice thanks for your help but unfortunate what i class modification also disturbing my other website pages aswell, Now in easy word i am saying.. sorry for confusing, well see: http://www.avanzasolutions.com/  in this website top link there is highlighted link "Product and services" which is basically not that page you can click it and see its own page but i don;t know on home page why its highlighting. :s

Comment: Do you want the `current-menu-ancestor` and  `current-menu-parent` class removed from that menu item because it is the home page? If so, you can either check for `is_home()` when removing the classes, or alternatively check for the class for that particular menu ID - in the case of "Products and Services" it is `menu-item-248`

Comment: Yeah want to remove from homepage

Comment: Can type code again with if is_front_page(), your whole code.

Comment: `is_home()` or `is_front_page()` should both work, code updated above.

Comment: The updated code executing on all pages and second i found this class "menu-item-object-avanza_serv_page" where curent class are adding on home page.

Comment: Mate your code is working fine now but it remove classes from all links, i just want to remove class from specific class link.

Comment: mate where are yu i am close to my task yet .. please help me.

Comment: I just noticed that you should be using `array_diff` to remove the unwanted classes, please try the code above. For more info read here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php